# I keep running into issues with web.py

Tags: python, debugging, web.py

Okay, so I actually had an issue with this line of code beforehand but I realized, thanks to a fellow answer from this site, that I had to delete my `web.py` folder from my directory and reinstall an updated version. I decided to go with the developer version.

Upon doing so I noticed that my initial run of code worked, but after I updated it and refreshed my browser, I got a huge error. I have tried to fix this several times, and I reinstalled like 10 times. I went into `debugger.py` and found no real solution, as every time I updated it the code refused to run.

To better illustrate my error this is my code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
class index:
    def GET(self, name):
        print ("Hello", name, '. How are you today?')
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

It runs without an error, but when open my page or refresh it after an initial run, it gives me this:

[image]

Error:

> <class 'AttributeError'> at /
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Now keep in mind that my first run works, and if I restart my computer or reinstall `web.py`, it works the first time every time. But after that initial run, it just gives me the above error on the webpage.

Comment: When you say "runs without error", are you able to get the first page to return "Hello <name> . How are you today?", or does "runs without error just mean you execute python without error, but it causes error on first page open?

Comment: Yes, it does return "Hello <name>"

Comment: On the surface, your code is fine, so that leads me to believe you may have a local file named in a way that clashes with python library... One way to approach this is simply code this, line-by-line into the python interpreter & see where it breaks. For example, can you type `import web` at the python3 prompt `>>>`? If so, which `web.py` is being picked up (hint: type `web` at the prompt after import an it should show you the path.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens only when you have made some changes to your script. You can stop script (`ctrl+c`) and start it again, everything should work fine.

But i found workaround.
On the top of your script (after imports) write:

```
__name__ = '<your main file name>'  # main2 for main2.py in my case
```

on the bottom replace

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

with

```
if __spec__ is None:
```

---

So the full script (main2.py) should look like:

```
import web
__name__ = 'main2'


urls = ("/.*", "hello")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, world1!'

if __spec__ is None:
    app.run()
```